# Installed LLVM on OS X with brew but no path were set to the executable

Tags: classpath, llvm

I installed LLVM on OS X with brew by `brew install llvm` and I tested it with `hello.c` with llvm-gcc, and it generates the IR for me. However, when I want to execute the IR code with `lli hello.ll` or compile it to assembler by `llc hello.ll`, `clang hello.s -x assembler -o hello` and run it with `./hello`. I got `-bash: lli: command not found` error. So I tried to add the class path as: `export CLASSPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/bin/lli:$CLASSPATH"`. However, I still didn't add the class path successfully. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: The PATH is what you want to modify not the CLASSPATH

Comment: I replaced CLASSPATH by PATH, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: For my brew install I have this path: export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH note that it is not the Cellar location

Comment: @FrankC. Your solution is correct, It works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the actual path where executables located is in opt. So `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"` should set the environment variables for llvm.

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/<version>/bin` for M1.

Comment: they are also in `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin` on my M1